# Can Pauli exclusion be described locally?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle

Is it possible, in principle, to define the exclusion principle in a "local" sense, as a property of the tangent space at a point, or a single fiber of a spin bundle? Or does it necessitate a global description, e.g. coordinate-free field operators?

As a hypothetical example to capture the spirit of the question, could infinitesimal probability and spin currents interact in a manifestly exclusive way? I'm not holding my breath, because for all I know, the "locality" I allude to is ill-defined, up to interpretation and precluded by ten different no-go theorems. :)